# Virtual host works on phone, but it loads the wrong thing

Tags: apache

I have MAMP running in my computer and the virtual host project.dev configured and working correctly (have been working on the project for years). Now I added project.dev to the hosts file on my Android phone, pointing to my local IP.

I access http://project.dev in mobile Chrome and it reaches my MAMP just fine, but it loads whatever is in /htdocs (basically as if I accessed "localhost" on my computer's browser), instead of loading the virtual host. This is how I've defined the virtual host in my httpd.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost project.dev
<VirtualHost project.dev:80>
    ServerName project.dev
    ServerAlias *.project.dev
    DocumentRoot "/project/public/root"

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|swf|ico|txt|html|mp3)$
    RewriteRule ^/(.+) /index.php [QSA,L]

    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
</VirtualHost>
```

Why isn't it executing that rule and loading the correct file and defaulting to MAMP's htdocs directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost :80> # Specify IP here, not hostname. You can leave it at :80 too (Listen on any)
 ServerName project.dev # For HTTP Host header
 ServerAlias *.project.dev # Same thing. I'm not sure if wildcards work.
 DocumentRoot /project/public/root

 yada yada yada
</VirtualHost>
```